# is SQLite representing unicode as an american flag

Tags: ruby-on-rails, unicode, utf-8, sqlite

In a Rails app, I have the following unicode characters within a row in a column of type: text

```
\U0001F64F\U0001F1FA\U0001F1F8-
```

When I output this in the rails console by calling the module name: Module.find(id).text

It prints it as a small American flag:

[image]

Can anyone explain what's happening here? I've read that SQLite uses UTF-8 and UTF-16 for encoding text but I'm not sure if this is due to SQLite or is it something else.

Comment: What is the output of `SELECT hex(MyColumn) FROM MyTable`? Is it correct UTF-8?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first character in the text is U+1F64F PERSON WITH FOLDED HANDS, which, according to comments in the Unicode code chart “can indicate sorrow or regret” and “can indicate pleading”. You won’t find it in most fonts, so in rendering, you may well see a small rectangle or nothing.

The next two are U+1F1FA REGIONAL INDICATOR SYMBOL LETTER U and U+1F1F8 REGIONAL INDICATOR SYMBOL LETTER S. The relevant [code chart](http://unicode.org/charts/PDF/U1F100.pdf) says about such characters: “These characters can be used in pairs to represent regionalcodes. In some emoji implementations, certain pairs may be recognized and displayed by alternate means; for instance, an implementation might recognize F + R and display this
combination with a symbol representing the flag of France.”

So it’s up to the rendering software to display them as the character pair “US” or to show an iconic US flag. Most programs won’t do either of these but will treat them as unknown data.